# Counting negative values in list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, pattern-matching

I would like to count the negative values of a list.

My approach was `Count[data, -_]` which doesn't work.

How can I tell *Mathematica* to count all numbers with a negative sign?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I assume that you have numeric values. A much more efficient way would be

```
-Total[UnitStep[data] - 1]]
```

or

```
Total[1-UnitStep[data]]
```

Note: While the second notation is certainly a bit more compact, it is about 35% slower than the double-minus notation. I have no idea why. On my system, it takes on average 0.22 sec vs 0.30 sec.

Compare timings between the faster UnitStep version and the pattern matching approach:

```
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10^7];

Timing[-Total[UnitStep[data] - 1]]
(* ==> {0.222, 5001715} *)

Timing[Count[data, _?Negative]]
(* ==> {6.734, 5001715} *)
```

Comment: `Total[1 - UnitStep[data]]` is more compact, no?

Comment: @J.M. Clever!!! I will edit according to your comment. However, it seams to make the code slightly slower. Any idea why?

Comment: I get the same timings on my machine. Did you notice that it turns around for shorter `data`? (Try 100 or so.)

Comment: The faster version does two negations but both applied to numbers, while the slow version negates a whole list

Answer (score 25):

Use `_?Negative`:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 30]

Count[list, _?Negative]
```

---

Your pattern will match an object with an explicit negative sign:

```
Count[{a, -b, c, a, -a, a, -b}, -_]
```

> 3

You could combine the patterns to match either:

```
Count[{-1, -2, 3, 4, -a, b, -c}, -_ | _?Negative]
```

> 4

---

Since this has become a speed competition (which is fine by me), rather than the beginner's question I took it to be, here is my own variation, using `Tr` for fast packed array summing:

```
neg = Length@# - Tr@UnitStep@# &;
```

Timings:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := Do[
    If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}],
    {i, 0, 15}
  ]

list = RandomInteger[1*^7 {-1, 1}, 1*^8];

-Total[UnitStep[list] - 1] // timeAvg

Length[list] - Total[UnitStep[list]] // timeAvg

neg @ list // timeAvg
```

> 0.592
>
> 0.234
>
> 0.1278

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that the latter solution only works for variables with an added minus, not for values.

Comment: Okay, so expanding on this question, are the easiest ways to find all values in the list less than, say, 5 `Length[list] - Total[UnitStep[list - 5]]` using the `UnitStep` method? Or is there another pattern match to use?

Comment: @kalewallace pattern matching methods are easier, more declarative and more general, but when everything is numeric, the other methods are way faster. `Count[list, i_/;i<5]`

Comment: @kalewallace you may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6027120/618728) of interest.  But, as Rojo states there is a trade-off, with patterns being more general and often conceptually simpler, while numeric approaches are usually faster given the right data (packed arrays of machine size reals or integers).

Comment: Just a side note.I was testing a solution, `ListPlot[(Reap@
     Do[Sow[Total@Clip[list, {0, 0}, {1, 0}] // timeAvg], {10}])[[2, 
    1]], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}, 
  Joined -> True] ` and timeAvg displays [a large  standard deviation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xefdy.png)

Comment: Looks like this is a very nice approach. However, this doesn't work if one wants to count complex numbers in a list. I also tried the straight away form (where ev is the list of numbers): `count[];
For[u = 1, u <= 6, u++,
  If[Abs[Im[ev[[u]]] > 10^-10], count++];
  ];` But no results...Maybe somebody has already done something like that?

Comment: @Anastasiia your comment: "this doesn't work if one wants to count complex numbers" doesn't make much sense as complex numbers are not simply positive or negative.  Perhaps you just want `Count[dat, _Complex]` to count all complex numbers in `dat`, or `Count[cr, _?(Im@# > 0 &)]` to count all numbers with an imaginary part greater than zero?

Comment: Thanks! I was trying out something similar by putting imaginary parts into a separate list and then checking the length of it...

Answer (score 19):

For numeric values, the following:

```
Length[data] - Total[UnitStep[data]]
```

is 50% faster than Thomas' solution.

**Update**: An even faster approach will be to compile to C, as shown in the following function `f`:

```
ClearAll[f];
f = Compile[{{vector, _Real, 1}, {bound, _Real}},
      Module[{t = 0, i = 1, len = Length[vector]}, 
        For[i = 1, i <= len, i++, t += Boole[vector[[i]] < bound]]; t], 
      CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
```

Using the timeAvg function, as defined in Mr. Wizard's answer, we have:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 
    15}];

data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10^7];

{-Total[UnitStep[data] - 1] // timeAvg,
 Length[data] - Total[UnitStep[data]] // timeAvg,
 Length[data] - Tr[UnitStep[data]] // timeAvg,
 f[data, 0.] // timeAvg}

(* ==> {0.105993, 0.0431972, 0.0422639, 0.0141324} *)
```

Note that the function `f` defined above will work for any upper bound, and not just 0. And would be significantly faster (at least in my machine) than the corresponding `Length[data]- Tr[UnitStep[data - bound]]` approach when `bound` is not zero.

For the dangers with the use of `"RuntimeOptions"->"Speed"`, see the Mathematica help: [RuntimeOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuntimeOptions.html).

Answer (score 7):

This seems competitive in terms of speed:

```
Total@Clip[list, {0, 0}, {1, 0}]
```

Testing:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
$HistoryLength = 0;
timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
neg = Length@# - Tr@UnitStep@# &;
list = RandomReal[1*^7 {-1, 1}, 1*^7];

Total@Clip[list, {0, 0}, {1, 0}] // timeAvg
-Total[UnitStep[list] - 1] // timeAvg
Length[list] - Total[UnitStep[list]] // timeAvg
neg@list // timeAvg

(* 0.1594, 0.375, 0.1812, 0.197 *)
```

Comment: Interesting, although in my machine this new one is still significantly slower than the last two.

Answer (score 6):

I've found the fastest way to do this sort of thing is to use a very simple procedural `Do` loop compiled to `C`.

```
f2 = Compile[{{numbers, _Real, 1}}, 
  Block[{count = 0}, Do[If[number < 0., count++], {number, numbers}]; 
   count], CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Lots of nice answers. Here's another, but I'm afraid it's quite slow.

```
Total[Select[data, # < 0 &]]
```

Though this totals all the negative numbers. To count them you could do:

```
-Total[Sign[Select[data, # < 0 &]]]
```

Then I got to thinking, "how would I program this in Matlab?"

```
 Total[1 - Sign[data]]/2
```

Comment: For the last one, this would be significantly faster: (Length[data] - Total[Sign[data]])/2, for the same reasons Rojo stated in Thomas' answer.

Comment: good point -- thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another one:

```
Total@Boole@Negative@data
```

Answer (score 3):

As a short variant

```
Count[data, x_ /; x < 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `GroupBy`

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 30];

Length @ GroupBy[list, Sign][-1]
```

16

```
Length @ GroupBy[list, Sign][#] & /@ {-1, 0, 1}
```

{16, 1, 13}

Answer (score 2):

Using `CountsBy`:

```
list = {-9, 1, 1, -4, -9, -3, 1, -9, 4, 3, 4, -5, 8, -5, -2, -9};

CountsBy[list, Sign][-1]

(*9*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more just because. I ma grabbing the list from @E. Chan-López

```
list = {-9, 1, 1, -4, -9, -3, 1, -9, 4, 3, 4, -5, 8, -5, -2, -9};
```

to begin with

```
Select[list, Negative] // Length
```

also

```
DeleteCases[list, x_ /; ! MatchQ[x, _?Negative]] // Length
```

furthermore

```
Pick[list, Negative[list]] // Length
```

and finally

```
Pick[#, 1 - HeavisideTheta@#, 1] &@list // Length
```