# Counting numbers in a range in a vector

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to count the number of numbers lying between 0 and -1 in a vector called `spec`.

I have tried `Count[spec,spec<0 && spec>-1]`, but this does not work. There must be an easy answer...

Comment: Old duplicate on Stack Overflow: [(6026827)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6026827/618728).  Related: [(9637)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9637/121)

Answer (score 10):

```
SeedRandom[1]
spec = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 100];

Tr[(1 - UnitStep[spec]) UnitStep[spec -(-1)]]
Tr@Unitize@Clip[spec, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}]
Count[spec, _?(-1 <= # <= 0 &)]
```

all give

> 24

Some timings:

```
SeedRandom[1]
s = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 10^6]; 
Grid[{#, ClearSystemCache[]; AbsoluteTiming[#[s]]} & /@ {
  Length@ Pick[#, Sign@Clip[#, {-1, 0}, {1, 1}], -1] &,
  Tr[(1 - UnitStep[#]) UnitStep[# - (-1)]] &,
  Tr@Unitize@Clip[#, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}] &,
  Count[#, _?(-1 <= # <= 0 &)] &,
  Total[Boole[-1 <= # <= 0] & /@ #] &,
  Length@Select[#, And[# > -1, # < 0] &] &,
  Length@Cases[#, x_ /; -1 < x < 0] &} ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

For `SeedRandom[1];s = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 10^7];` we get:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: Still on version 9, so cannot include `CountsBy` in the timings table.

Comment: Great, but why is the condition syntax different from Select []?

Comment: @Morgan, The second argument of `Count` is a _pattern_ (see  [Count](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Count.html)), while the second argument of `Select` is a boolean function (see [Select](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html))

Comment: @Morgan see [(18054)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18054/121), [(88220)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88220/121)

Answer (score 4):

```
Total[Boole[-1 <= # <= 0] & /@ spec]
```

Comment: Isn't `Unitize` redundant?

Comment: @Coolwater d'oh...I have amended. I had an answer that used `Unitize` and didn't think. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1]
spec = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 100];

CountsBy[spec, -1 <= # <= 0 &]
```

[image]

```
CountsBy[spec, -1 <= # <= 0 &][True]
```

> 24

**Update**

This one is very fast:

```
s = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 10^6];

Length @ Pick[s, Sign @ Clip[s, {-1, 0}, {1, 1}], -1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.032002, 249536}

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[spec, And[# > -1, # < 0] &] // Length
```

Comment: For what it's worth, if you change it to `Select[spec, -1 < # < 0 &] // Length` it gets considerably faster on large lists.

Comment: Nice, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];
spec = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 100000];

Length@Cases[spec, x_ /; -1 < x < 0]
```

> 25288