# Speed of a simple operation over a long list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

What is the fastest procedure for counting elements smaller than 0.5 in a large list?

For example let

```
list=RandomReal[1, 10000000];
```

For a number of elements less than 0.5

```
Length[Select[list, # < 0.5 &] ] // Timing
```

> `{6.20313, 4996170}`

```
Count[list, _?(# < 0.5 &)] // Timing
```

> `{7.75, 4996170}`

```
Total[Table[Boole[list[[k]] < 0.5] // N, {k, 1, Length[list]}]] // Timing
```

> `{3.5625, 4.99617*10^6}`

```
Total[(Sign[list - 0.5] + 1)/2] // Timing
```

> `{3.625, 5003830}`

**But** for example

```
list.list // Timing
```

> `{0., 3.33561*10^6}`

So the length of the list is not so big, rather the procedures used are slow. What's the faster way?

Comment: closely related: [9637](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9637/5478)

Comment: I am curious that anyone provides the processor and OS used for comparison in the same working conditions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1234];
list = RandomReal[1, 10000000];
Length[Select[list, # < 0.5 &]] // RepeatedTiming
Total[UnitStep[0.5 - list]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {4.77, 4998698}
>
> {0.0698, 4998698}

And skipping multiplying `list` with `-1.`, these are even a bit faster:

```
Length[list] - Total[UnitStep[list - 0.5]] // RepeatedTiming
Total[UnitStep[Subtract[0.5, list]]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.048, 4998698}
>
> {0.050, 4998698}

Building on a compiled version by @ecoxlinux from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9637/counting-negative-values-in-list) (linked by Kuba), we can also define

```
countLessThan = Compile[{{vector, _Real, 1}, {bound, _Real}},
  Block[{counter = 0},
   Do[counter+=Boole[Compile`GetElement[vector, i]<bound], {i, 1, Length[vector]}];
   counter],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
```

and use

```
countLessThan[list, 0.5] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0042, 4998698}

Answer (score 6):

If the list is shorter than 10^16 the `MachinePrecision` numbers one gets from `Clip` won't be too imprecise:

```
Total[(Sign[list - 0.5] + 1)/2] // AbsoluteTiming
Round[Clip[list, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}] // Total] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.8582906, 5002895}
>
> {0.13461055, 5002895}

Answer (score 6):

The fastest non-compiled approach is the one [shown by @Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160779/12), but I would like to point out a few subtleties about it.

You asked how many elements are *less than 0.5*. One of the proposed answers was `Total@UnitStep@Subtract[0.5, list]`.  However, this counts how many elements are *less than or equal to 0.5*. Note that `UnitStep[0]` is `1`.  The other proposed solution, `Length[list] - Total@UnitStep@Subtract[list, 0.5]`, is the correct one.  Or one that is somewhat more amenable to generalization: `Total[1 - UnitStep@Subtract[list, 0.5]]`.

The biggest problem with this approach is that it is hard to write and hard to read. As the answers above demonstrate, it is very easy to make small mistakes.  Consider a more complex situation, such as how many elements are within interval `[a, b) ∪ (c, d]` or similar.  It quickly becomes painful to write these expressions.

I have a small package called [BoolEval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/12) that helps with this: all it does is translate relational and Boolean operations to the kinds of arithmetic expressions Henrik has shown.

```
<<BoolEval`

BoolCount[list < 0.5] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.067, 4998698} *)

BoolCount[list <= 0.5] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.047, 4998698} *)

Total@UnitStep@Subtract[0.5, list] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.048, 4998698} *)
```

Comment: You made a very good point!

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the good performance of inner product, I find that the last one is not so bad:

```
Count[list - .5, _?Negative] // AbsoluteTiming

Count[list, _?(# < .5 &)] // AbsoluteTiming

Length[Select[list, # < .5 &]] // AbsoluteTiming

#.# &@UnitStep[.5 - list] // AbsoluteTiming
```

giving respectively

```
{2.94449, 5001117}

{4.62976, 5001117}

{4.11387, 5001117}

{0.0727141, 5001117}
```