# Number of sign flips in list?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, pattern-matching

Given a list of signs:

```
list={1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1};
```

how to most conveniently and quickly determine the number of sign flips in the sequence?

I have this ad-hoc solution:

```
flipNum[l_]:=Block[{num},
  num=0;
  Do[If[0>l[[i]]l[[i+1]],num=num+1;];,{i,1,Length[l]-1}];
  If[0>l[[1]]l[[-1]],num=num+1;];
  num
]
```

But I suspect there could exist a much quicker and more elegant solution in mathematica?

**EDIT:**

While it is true that the above code is very slow (takes 20 seconds in the benchmarks in the answers below), one can easily compile it:

```
flipNum = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, Block[{num}, num = 0;
   Do[If[0 > l[[i]] l[[i + 1]], num = num + 1;];, {i, 1, Length[l] - 1}];
   If[0 > l[[1]] l[[-1]], num = num + 1;];
   num], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

With this the performance becomes:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
list = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 10000000];
AbsoluteTiming[flipNum[list]]
```

> `{0.282849, 5000678}`

which makes it actually the most efficient solution without packaging the data.

If we do package the data:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
list = RandomChoice[Developer`ToPackedArray@{-1, 1}, 10^7];
AbsoluteTiming[flipNum[list]]
```

> `{0.224196, 5000678}`

it gets a bit quicker, but loses in terms of performance to the "bitxor" and "subtract" solutions.

Comment: At least somewhat related: [(9637)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9637/121), [(10640)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10640/121), [(31771)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31771/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your list doesn't contain `0` you can do

```
list = {1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1};

Total[Abs[Differences[Sign[list]]]]/2 + Boole[Sign[First[list]] != Sign[Last[list]]]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Accounting for the cyclic sign flip this way isn't as elegant, but in kglr's test it's much faster than using `Append[list, First[list]]`.

Comment: Note that my `flipNum[list]` returns `6`, since the sign flip between first and last list element also counts.

Comment: Add `Abs[Sign[list[[1]]] - Sign[list[[-1]]]]/2` to the result to account for cyclic sign flips between first and last list elements.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Ah, I didn't realize that was a requirement. See me edit.

Answer (score 17):

```
list = {1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1};

Total[Unitize[Subtract[list, RotateRight @ list]]]
```

> 6

```
Total @ Abs @ Subtract[list, RotateRight@list]/2
```

> 6

```
Length[Split[Append[list, list[[1]]]]] - 1
```

> 6

### Timings

#### Functions

```
split = Length[Split[Append[#, #[[1]]]]] - 1 &;
fold = With[{f = First[#], r = Rest[#]}, 
    Block[{o}, If[f == r[[-1]], o = {0, f}, o = {1, f}];
     First[Fold[With[{c = #1[[1]], s1 = #1[[-1]], s2 = #2}, 
         If[s1 == s2, {c, s2}, {c + 1, s2}]] &, o, r]]]] &;
bitxor = Total@Unitize@BitXor[#, RotateRight[#]] &;
bitxor2[list_] := -Total@BitXor[list, RotateRight@list]/2
subtract = Total@Unitize@Subtract[#, RotateRight@#] &;
subtract2 = Total@Abs@Subtract[#, RotateRight@#]/2 &;
differences = Total[Abs[Differences[Sign@#]]]/2 + Boole[Sign[First[#]] != Sign[Last[#]]]&;
flips = With[{q = Split[Positive[#]][[All, 1]]}, Length[q]-Boole[First[q] === Last[q]]]&;
partition = -Total[Cases[Apply[Times, Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, 1}], 1], Except[1]]] &;
flipNum[l_] := Block[{num}, num = 0;
  Do[If[0 > l[[i]] l[[i + 1]], num = num + 1;];, {i, 1, Length[l] - 1}];
      If[0 > l[[1]] l[[-1]], num = num + 1;];  num]
ProgressiveDifferences[list_] := Reverse[Differences[Reverse[list]]];
WrappingDifferences[list_] := Append[ProgressiveDifferences[list], 
  list[[Length[list]]] - list[[1]]]/2;
wrappingdifs = Total[Abs[WrappingDifferences[#]]] &;
count = Count[# + RotateRight@#, 0] &;
count2= Length[#] - Total[Abs[# + RotateRight@#]]/2 &;
listconvolve = Count[ListConvolve[{1, 1}, #, 1], 0] &;
listconvolve2 = Length[#] - Total[Abs[ListConvolve[{1, 1}, #, 1]]]/2 &;

funcs = {flips, split, fold, bitxor, subtract, subtract2, differences,
 flipNum, partition, bitxor2, count,count2, listconvolve, listconvolve2, wrappingdifs};
labels = {"flips", "split", "fold", "bitxor", "subtract", 
 "subtract2", "differences", "flipNum", "partition", "bitxor2", 
 "count","countt2", "listconvolve", "listconvolve2", "wrappingdifs"};
```

#### Timings for unpacked input

For unpacked input data, Alucard & Chip Hurst's `listconvolve2` is the fastest among the methods posted so far followed by `differences`.

**Version 9.0 on Windows 10 - 64bit**

```
SeedRandom[1234]
list = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 10^7];
{timing, output} = Transpose[AbsoluteTiming[#[list]] & /@ funcs];
TeXForm @ Grid[Prepend[SortBy[Transpose[{labels, output, timing}], Last], 
  {"function", "output", "timing"}], Dividers -> All]
```

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{function} & \text{output} & \text{timing} \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve2} & 5000678 & 0.327872 \\
\hline
 \text{differences} & 5000678 & 0.392042 \\
\hline
 \text{subtract2} & 5000678 & 0.435157 \\
\hline
 \text{subtract} & 5000678 & 0.440169 \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor2} & 5000678 & 0.533418 \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor} & 5000678 & 0.536427 \\
\hline
 \text{count2} & 5000678 & 0.538431 \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve} & 5000678 & 0.737962 \\
\hline
 \text{count} & 5000678 & 0.975595 \\
\hline
 \text{fold} & 5000678 & 1.226261 \\
\hline
 \text{split} & 5000678 & 1.455870 \\
\hline
 \text{flips} & 5000678 & 2.982931 \\
\hline
 \text{wrappingdifs} & 5000678 & 3.439143 \\
\hline
 \text{partition} & 5000678 & 7.361212 \\
\hline
 \text{flipNum} & 5000678 & 20.259868 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Version 11.2 on windows 10-64bit**

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{function} & \text{output} & \text{timing} \\
\hline
 \text{subtract} & 5000678 & 0.459002 \\
\hline
 \text{subtract2} & 5000678 & 0.476543 \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve2} & 5000678 & 0.501648 \\
\hline
 \text{count2} & 5000678 & 0.517032 \\
\hline
 \text{count} & 5000678 & 1.02226 \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve} & 5000678 & 1.1516 \\
\hline
 \text{fold} & 5000678 & 1.35075 \\
\hline
 \text{split} & 5000678 & 1.42508 \\
\hline
 \text{flips} & 5000678 & 2.39839 \\
\hline
 \text{differences} & 5000678 & 3.14381 \\
\hline
 \text{wrappingdifs} & 5000678 & 3.23569 \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor} & 5000678 & 3.92984 \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor2} & 5000678 & 4.66418 \\
\hline
 \text{partition} & 5000678 & 5.09891 \\
\hline
 \text{flipNum} & 5000678 & 19.1239 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

#### Timings for PackedArray input

**Version 9.0 on Windows 10 - 64bit**

Using a packed array as input, `subtract2` is the fastest followed by `subtract`.

```
SeedRandom[1234]
list = RandomChoice[Developer`ToPackedArray@{-1, 1}, 10^7];
{timing, output} = Transpose[AbsoluteTiming[#[list]] & /@ funcs];
TeXForm @ Grid[Prepend[SortBy[Transpose[{labels, output, timing}], Last],
  {"function", "output", "timing"}], Dividers -> All]
```

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{function} & \text{output} & \text{timing} \\
\hline
 \text{subtract} & 5000678 & 0.211562 \\
\hline
 \text{count2} & 5000678 & 0.212565 \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor} & 5000678 & 0.242641 \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve2} & 5000678 & 0.259692 \\
\hline
 \text{subtract2} & 5000678 & 0.295785 \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor2} & 5000678 & 0.326869 \\
\hline
 \text{differences} & 5000678 & 0.332885 \\
\hline
 \text{count} & 5000678 & 0.629674 \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve} & 5000678 & 0.694850 \\
\hline
 \text{fold} & 5000678 & 1.269379 \\
\hline
 \text{split} & 5000678 & 2.291084 \\
\hline
 \text{wrappingdifs} & 5000678 & 3.368954 \\
\hline
 \text{flips} & 5000678 & 5.188834 \\
\hline
 \text{partition} & 5000678 & 8.494586 \\
\hline
 \text{flipNum} & 5000678 & 22.879290 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Version 11.2 on windows 10-64bit(Alucard i5-6300u)**

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{function} & \text{output} & \text{timing} \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor2} & 5000678 & 0.159978 \\
\hline
 \text{count2} & 5000678 & 0.170289 \\
\hline
 \text{subtract2} & 5000678 & 0.176443 \\
\hline
 \text{bitxor} & 5000678 & 0.18276 \\
\hline
 \text{subtract} & 5000678 & 0.184796 \\
\hline
 \text{differences} & 5000678 & 0.344954 \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve2} & 5000678 & 0.40738 \\
\hline
 \text{count} & 5000678 & 0.665442 \\
\hline
 \text{listconvolve} & 5000678 & 0.891994 \\
\hline
 \text{fold} & 5000678 & 1.42892 \\
\hline
 \text{split} & 5000678 & 1.64534 \\
\hline
 \text{flips} & 5000678 & 2.31116 \\
\hline
 \text{wrappingdifs} & 5000678 & 3.0645 \\
\hline
 \text{partition} & 5000678 & 5.5853 \\
\hline
 \text{flipNum} & 5000678 & 22.0245 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: I have the feeling that this one will be quicker than the approach using `Differences`.

Comment: Would go with this one though, to account for cyclic boundary:
`Length[SplitBy[Sign[list], Sign]] - 1 + Abs[Sign[list[[1]]] - Sign[list[[-1]]]]/2`

Comment: Note that my `flipNum[list]` returns `6`, since the sign flip between first and last list element also counts.

Comment: Thank you for the timing comparison! On my machine, adding `Abs[Sign[list[[1]]] - Sign[list[[-1]]]]/2` to Chip Hurst's answer to account for the possible difference due to cyclicity does not make it slower. Will accept his answer as the most efficient one.

Comment: Observe that built-in function `SequenceCount` is obnoxiously slow:  `builtin = SequenceCount[#, {-1, 1} | {1, -1}, Overlaps -> True] &;`  This is an example where using a built-in function that performs your task *is not advisable*!

Comment: You might want to repeat the test with packed data.

Comment: @Carl,  yes! thank you. How quickly we forget!

Comment: @kglr it seems that the definitions of   "differences" and "flipnum"  are missing

Comment: My version of `bitxor` is different than yours, and faster to boot (at least for the packed case).

Comment: @CarlWoll, added the second variant of `bitxor`.

Comment: It's weird that your timings are so different from mine.

Comment: @kglr mine are different too, the fastest option for packed arrays is bitxor2, while for unpacked arrays the fastest is subtract (v 11.2)

Comment: @Alucard, it is probably version difference. Do you mind posting v11.2 timings table using the code above? (I am using the free cloud version and cannot run this timing experiment on the free 11.2 version.)

Comment: @kglr should i replace the old table in your post or put them alongside the old one?

Comment: @kglr Thanks for the timings. You might want to add the updated version (based on Chip Hurst's comment) without Count. It seems to be faster.

Comment: @AnjanKumar it's the second fastest for packed arrays

Comment: @kglr: can you update also the name of the new function in my tables? since Anjan does not use count anymore  we need another name for the new function. I realized it only after updating

Comment: The comments getting a bit long (I got a moderator notice.)  Maybe time to roll anything important into the answer and purge.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my version:

```
Total @ Unitize @ BitXor[list, RotateRight[list]]
```

> 6

**Addendum**

Assuming the lists consist of only 1 and -1, then the [`BitXor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitXor) function call will return -2 (for sign changes) and 0 otherwise. So, we can dispense with the [`Unitize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unitize) part:

```
bitxor[list_] := -Total @ BitXor[list, RotateRight @ list]/2
```

This should be faster than the other answers as long as the input is packed. For example:

```
subtract[list_] := Total @ Unitize @ Subtract[list, RotateRight @ list]
differences[list_] := 1/2 Total[Abs[Differences[Sign[list]]]]+Boole[Sign[First[list]]!=Sign[Last[list]]]

data = RandomChoice[Developer`ToPackedArray @ {-1, 1}, 10^7];

r1 = bitxor[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = subtract[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r3 = differences[data]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.057, Null}
>
> {0.077, Null}
>
> {0.15, Null}
>
> True

If the input isn't packed, then the [`BitXor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitXor) approach becomes much slower, at least in M11.2.

Answer (score 9):

For fun:

```
Needs["LinearAlgebra`BLAS`"]

l2 = RotateRight[list];
AXPY[1, list, l2];
AbsoluteTiming[Length[list] - Total[Unitize@l2]]

(*{0.0435857, 5000678}*)
```

Comment: Nice one! Unfortunately, when I wrap all three lines in `AbsoluteTiming`, it becomes just as quick as the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh duh!  I knew I was cheating somehow....

Comment: chuy, i don't have the ``LinearAlgebra`BLAS`` package so I could not include this in the timing comparisons. Please feel free to add this to the table in my post. (+1)

Comment: oh its waaay slower.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach using [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html),

```
Count[list+ RotateRight @ list,0]
```

> 6

**Update**

This version seems to be much faster. Credits to Chip Hurst.

```
Length[#] - Total[Abs[# + RotateRight@#]]/2 & [list]
```

> 6

Answer (score 4):

```
Count[ ListConvolve[{1, 1}, list,1], 0]
```

Comment: Nice. You can avoid using `Count` with `Length[list] -
 Total[Abs[ListConvolve[{1, 1}, list, 1]]]/2`.

Comment: @ChipHurst  i tried evaluating the timing and with your suggestion it became 35% faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
flips = With[{q = Split[Positive[#]][[All, 1]]},
          Length[q] - Boole[First[q] === Last[q]]] &;
flips[list]
```

> 6

works only if `Length[list] >= 1` though

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1};
cycle = Append[#, First@#] &@list;
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
patt = s : {OrderlessPatternSequence[1, -1]} :> s;

Length@SequenceCases[cycle, patt, Overlaps -> True]

(*6*)
```

Answer (score 2):

for a list of *signs* `list={1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1};` the following code

```
With[{f = First[list], r = Rest[list]},
 Block[{o},
  If[f == r[[-1]], o = {0, f}, o = {1, f}];
  First[
   Fold[
    With[{c = #1[[1]], s1 = #1[[-1]], s2 = #2},
      If[
       s1 == s2,
       {c, s2},
       {c + 1, s2}
       ]
      ] &, o, r]]]]
```

evaluates to

> ```
> 6
> ```

PS. The same result is produced by

```
-Total[Cases[Apply[Times, Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 1}], 1], Except[1]]]
```

Comment: Note that my `flipNum[list]` returns `6`, since the sign flip between first and last list element also counts.

Answer (score 2):

An approach for when you like to think your list has periodic boundary conditions

```
ProgressiveDifferences[list_] :=  Reverse[Differences[Reverse[list]]]; 
(* returns a list of x_i - x_{i+1} instead of  x_{i+1} - x_i given by Differences *)

WrappingDifferences[list_] := Append[ProgressiveDifferences[list], list[[Length[list]]] - list[[1]]]/2; 
(* Difference gives an N-1 list, append the periodic boundary difference to that *)
```

Then

```
 q[list_] := Total[Abs[WrappingDifferences[list]]];
```

gives you the number of points where the signs disagree.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1};
```

For better readability

```
cycle = Append[list, First @ list];
```

With `SequenceCount`

```
SequenceCount[cycle, {1, -1} | {-1, 1}, Overlaps -> True]
```

6

With `DeleteCases`

```
Length @ DeleteCases[{a_, a_}] @ Partition[cycle, 2, 1]
```

6